# Workbox debug mode okay for public consumption?

Tags: service-worker, workbox, progressive-web-apps

I am a noob to PWA/Workbox so was wondering what is best practices for Workbox debug mode - is it okay for production/live site to leave debug mode enabled for Workbox ?

```
workbox.setConfig({
  debug: true
});
```

Or is there a way to dynamically enable it for just my own whitelisted IP addresses ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could leave it on, on production but that's probably not a good idea.
I'd only enable it on your `staging` environment, and disable it on your `production/live` environment